# Send message from controller Asp.Net Core SignalR

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Could anyone share link where describes how use IHubContext in right way? because i just confused what the purpose of my NotificationHub if i can send message directly from controller?

```
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
         public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
         {
             await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
         }
    }
```

What I called from my controller:

```
await hubContext.Clients.Client(user.Id.ToString()).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user.FirstName);
```

where hubcontext of type `IHubContext<NotificationHub>`

What's is the right way of sending messages from controller?

Answer (score 3):

> Could anyone share link where describes how use IHubContext in right way?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1

In your example code, what is the user id? Client.Client is for SignalR connection id. You want to use the UserId when sending to a specific user (`Clients.User`)

> because i just confused what the purpose of my NotificationHub if i can send message directly from controller?

If you don't want to use a controller then you use the hub for incoming data. You can use a controller if you want to support a purely HTTP API. You can use the Hub if you want to use WebSockets (or the other transports SignalR supports) to receive incoming data.

It'a also useful for handling connection lifetime events like OnConnectedAsync and OnDisconnectedAsync. This lets you perform actions when a particular connection connects or disconnects.

Comment: So if i want just send direct message from controller my NotificationHub is not used? Message sends directly going around NotificationHub?

Comment: > So if i want just send direct message from controller my NotificationHub is not used?

It's always used. It's just not used for incoming data.